# NextJS: Best way to handle Connect / OwnProps / GetInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

`<App foo="123" />`

```
@connect((state) => state, () => {})
class App extends Component
```

And I'd like to render App with 123.
But, if state in MapStateToProps has a `foo` key and its value is `abc`, the component will render `abc`.

I could check ownProps.

```
@connect((state, ownProps) => ({...state, ...ownProps}), () => {})
class App extends Component
```

and merge ownProps and state. But If I start dispatching actions to update foo in Redux, state will always be `abc`. ownProps will always override keys in state.

I could dispatch an action when the component mounts.

```
componentDidMount() {
  dispatchFoo(this.props.value)
}
```

when component mounts, I'm dispatching the value 
@connect((state) => state, () => {})`

Store will be updated with `abc`, the value of the own props.
Redux will update and the component will render once more.
But this time, state will be `abc` in ..

`@connect((state) => state, () => {})`

What is the best way to set something like this up? Preferably that doesn't require the component to render twice (I'm using SSR).

In my case, I'm using NextJS and making an API call to fetch data in getInitialProps. Return of getInitialProps puts data on props. Those props are given to App. When user changes state, the App needs data from state now, not props

Comment: Why would you pass the same prop key to the component in two different places/in two different ways? (aka connect and inline). That sounds like a really error prone way to write code.

Comment: I'm not. I'm passing App the prop `foo` with value `123`. After which, user action change the value of `foo` via redux. Connect maps the store state to props. And state has the `foo` key.

Comment: Yes, exactly what im describing. Why would your state in redux have a key that is identical to an inline prop? You should have separate prop keys for what you want to send inline from what is in the connected store

Comment: I'm using NextJS and making an API call to fetch data in `getInitialProps`. Return of `getInitialProps` puts data on props. Those props are given to `App`. When user changes state, the App needs data from state now, not props. Can you elaborate on how to use this `separate prop`?

Comment: Don't pass `foo` as a prop on the component, let connect pass that prop. If you need a different value there initially, then set the store up with that initial value

Comment: More of a NextJS question but, is it best to dispatch after fetching in `getInitialProps` and @connect this component? AFIAK the component would render twice. The first time returning initial props from getInitialProps. The second time responding to the dispatch in `getInitialProps`. At which point, the data dispatched would be in state.

Comment: You shouldn't really need initial props. You should let the store define the data always. Initial props is scoped only to one component. You should follow the redux pattern for where to dispatch, where to make requests .. etc. I'd recommend a reducer file for your storage, an action file for dispatching actions and a thunk file for making api requests. These files could be under a folder called `users` for instance if it's the stuff related to users. Does that make sense?

Comment: When rendering a component with NextJS getInitialProps is a life cycle method. I have separate actions / reducers / etc.  When a component is SSR'ed in Next its recommended to use getInitialProps to fetch data. Like I've explained, `getInitialProps` puts whatever is returned ON props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i am not wrong you want to implement something known as uncontrolled components. If so I will suggest you to implement it in following way.

```
Class Page extends React.Component{
  static getInitialProps(){
    return {foo:"Some Value"}
  }
  render(){
    return <Provider store={createStore(reducer,{foo:this.props.foo})}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>

  }
}
```

Then your app.js will be

```
@connect(mapStateToProps,{dispatchFoo})
Class App extends React.Component{
 componentDidMount(){
   this.props.dispatchFoo({foo:"some new value"});
 }
 render(){
   <div>{this.props.foo}</div>
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

**1. use defaultProps**

> defaultProps can be defined as a property on the component class itself, to set the default props for the class. This is used for undefined props, but not for null props. For example:

```
App.defaultProps = {
    foo: true
};
```

See [defaultProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) from React's blog.

**2. setup an initial state**

Inside your reducer you can set your state initial values, that values will be available via `mapStateToProps`:

```
const initialState = {
    foo: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log('action', action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.SOME_ACTION:
            return {
                ...state,
            foo: true
            };
        case types.ANOTHER_ACTION:
            return {
                ...state,
                foo: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In general, I don't see any point of overriding the same props inside `mapStateToProps` as it should prevent your app from being updated by redux.