# Pass data from page to another

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I recently started working with next.js, although I already have some experience with react, I have the following folder structure:

```
/segments 
  -index.js
  -[slug].js
```

Scenario: On page  `[url] / segments` I get the list of segments by making a call to my api, which returns an array with all the information for each segment -> I display the list of segments for the user -> User chooses the segment and navigates to  `[url] / segments / slug`. At this point I would like that on this page `[slug] .js` to receive the segment that the user chose (since everything I need is already in the object) without the need for another call to the api.
I know I can use context for this, but I was wondering if next.js can solve this problem without having to use the global scope. Just passing a fetched data on one page to another.
Thanks All

Comment: If this was `react-router` or something similar, I would say pass the data via routing. NextJS doesn't offer this atm but there are "hacky" ways to do this like `localStorage`, etc.

Comment: meet [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js: Reduce data fetching and share data between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899880/next-js-reduce-data-fetching-and-share-data-between-pages)

Answer (score 1):

You must take advantage of custom `_app.js` to share data among your application.

I have answered in detail to the same question which you can check it out in the following link:

[Next.js: Reduce data fetching and share data between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899880/next-js-reduce-data-fetching-and-share-data-between-pages/61131312#61131312)