# Next JS fetch data once to display on all pages

Tags: next.js

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899880/next-js-reduce-data-fetching-and-share-data-between-pages) is the most relevant information I can find but it isn't enough.

I have a generic component that displays an appbar for my site. This appbar displays a user avatar that comes from a separate API which I store in the users session. My problem is that anytime I change pages through `next/link` the avatar disappears unless I implement `getServerSideProps` on every single page of my application to access the session which seems wasteful.

I have found that I can implement `getInitialProps` in `_app.js` like so to gather information

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
    await applySession(ctx.req, ctx.res);
    if(!ctx.req.session.hasOwnProperty('user')) {
        return {
            user: {
                avatar: null,
                username: null
            }
        }
    }

    let pageProps = {}
    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
        pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }
    return {
        user: {
            avatar: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${ctx.req.session.user.id}/${ctx.req.session.user.avatar}`,
            username: ctx.req.session.user.username
        },
        pageProps
    }
}
```

I think what's happening is this is being called client side on page changes where the session of course doesn't exist which results in nothing being sent to props and the avatar not being displayed. I thought that maybe I could solve this with local storage if I can differentiate when this is being called on the server or client side but I want to know if there are more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by creating a state in my `_app.js` and then setting the state in a `useEffect` like this

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, user }) {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState({});
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if(user.avatar) {
            setUserInfo(user);
        }
    });
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <NavDrawer user={userInfo} />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Now the user variable is only set once and it's sent to my NavDrawer bar on page changes as well.

Comment: will this be executed on every page rendering?

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this using `getServerSideProps()` in `_app.tsx`:

```js
// _app.tsx:

export type AppContextType = {
  navigation: NavigationParentCollection
}

export const AppContext = createContext<AppContextType>(null)

function App({ Component, pageProps, navigation }) {
  const appData = { navigation }
  return (
    <>
      <AppContext.Provider value={appData}>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </>
  )
}

App.getInitialProps = async function () {
  // Fetch the data and pass it into the App
  return {
    navigation: await getNavigation()
  }
}

export default App
```

Then anywhere inside the app:

```js
const { navigation } = useContext(AppContext)
```

To learn more about useContext check out the [React docs here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

Other current answers kind of prove what went wrong with React. It used to be simple.

Anyway use context is an overkill, just fetch and pass as props thats why props are there.

In most cases you dont want to pass entire Objects down the line, but neatly organized presentational props.

// _app.tsx:

```
function App({ Component, pageProps, navigation }) {
  const appData = // fetch whatever way you like, useEffect SWR etc.
  return (
        <div>
          <Component {...pageProps} appData={appData} />
        </div>
  )
}


export default App
```