# Next.js won't pass user prop in _app.tsx

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify, react-props

I want to pass the user object to all pages in my next.js app. I am getting nothing written to the console or passed as a prop with the following code. The amplify part seems to be working.

```
// _app.tsx

import type { AppProps } from "next/app"
import type { GetServerSideProps, GetServerSidePropsContext } from "next"
import Amplify, { Auth, withSSRContext } from "aws-amplify"
import { AmplifyAuthenticator, AmplifySignIn } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react"
import { config } from "../amplify.config"

Amplify.configure({ ...config, ssr: true })

MyApp.getServerSideProps = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    const appProps = await getServerSideProps(context)

    return { ...appProps }
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const auth = withSSRContext(ctx).Auth as typeof Auth

    let user: any
    try {
        user = await auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
        console.log("user is authenticated:", user)
        return { props: { user: user } }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error: no authenticated user")
    }
}

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <AmplifyAuthenticator>
            <AmplifySignIn hideSignUp usernameAlias="email" slot="sign-in" />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AmplifyAuthenticator>
    )
}
```

Comment: Custom _app in Next.js does not support getServerSideProps and getStaticProps. Try to use getInitiapProps instead.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  getInitialProps will work but causes your app to server side render every page.
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats

Answer (score 0):

Please read this part of the documentation for `next.js`

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

> App currently does not support Next.js Data Fetching methods like
> getStaticProps or getServerSideProps.

So you must make some changes in your `_app.js` to achieve that.

you can find the solution here in this post:
[Next.js: Reduce data fetching and share data between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899880/next-js-reduce-data-fetching-and-share-data-between-pages/61131312#61131312)