# NextJs: Check and set auth state on page change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

#### Want

I want my next application to hit the endpoint `/api/users/whoami` which basically validates the cookie and returns the payload of the user logged in

#### Have

I am using `ContextApi` to set the `authState` in my application.

The issue is, all this logic is in `_app.js` file's `useEffect` which is **OUTSIDE** `<AuthContextProvider>`

Thus, I  am unable to set the state (context) from inside of `_app.js`:

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { setAuthState, authState } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const whoAmI = async () => {
      const { data } = await api.get(AuthEndpoints.whoami);
      if (data) { //  setting state 
        setAuthState({ isAuthenticated: true, userId: data.id, username: data.username });
      } else {
        setAuthState({ isAuthenticated: false, userId: null, username: null });
      }
    };
    whoAmI();
  }, [Component]);

  console.log(authState); //  This wont update 

  return (
    <AuthContextProvider> // 
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Navbar />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: hi, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899880/next-js-reduce-data-fetching-and-share-data-between-pages

Comment: Move this `useEffect` inside the Context itself

Comment: But I want to add "Component" to the dependency array of the `useEffect` so that this request is made everytime the page is changed. Can I pass down the component itself to `<ContextProvder component={Component}>` as a prop and use it there?
Would that be ideal?