# Sharing/Fetching data per component in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch some data from my models, using `GraphQL` in order to dynamically prepopulate a Navbar by localization language:

```js
export async function getPageTitleBySlug(slug) {
  const data = await fetchAPI(
    `query PageTitleBySlug($where: JSON){
      pages(where: $where) {
        title_en
        title {
          title_es
          title_tr
        }
      }
    }`,
    {
      variables: {
        where: { slug },
      },
    }
  )

  return data
}
```

Quite easy.

I call this function from the **navbar** component with:

```js
export async function getLocalizedTitle(slug) {
  const data = await getPageTitleBySlug(slug)
  return { ...data?.pages[0] }
}
```

This function is called inside of the component with:

```js
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState(links.map(({ label }) => ({ [label]: "" })))

  useEffect(() => {
    links.map(async ({ label }) => {
      const { title, title_en } = await getLocalizedTitle(label)

      const localizedTitle =
        title[
          Object.keys(title).find(
            (content) => content.split("_")[1] == i18n.language
          )
        ] || title_en
      setLabels({ [label]: localizedTitle })
    })
  }, [i18n.language])
```

And it does works, because each time I change the local language, this effect is called.

My idea is getting the value from this dictionary inside of:

```js
        {links.map(({ key, href, label }) => (
          <MenuItem key={key}>
            <Link href={href}>
              <a></a>
            </Link>
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
```

Unfortunately, each time I call this function or refresh the site I get:
[image]

It is easy to realize the problem is in the fetch, but it just happens when I call the fetch from the component.

I tried to populate the data before to render the page but `getInitialProps` and `setStaticProps` just works for pages.

**UPDATE**
Following directions that I found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299970/nextjs-best-way-to-handle-connect-ownprops-getinitialprops), I made the next update:

```js
FolioApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)

  // TODO: Here at beginning is undefined, so, i'm getting errors in console, it should be a defaultProp, but how?
  let navProps = {}
  menu_links.map(async ({ label }) => {
    const { title, title_en } = await getLocalizedTitle(label)
    navProps[label] = { title, title_en }
  })

  const defaultProps = appContext.Component.defaultProps

  return {
    ...appProps,
    navProps,
    pageProps: {
      namespacesRequired: [
        ...(appProps.pageProps.namespacesRequired || []),
        ...(defaultProps?.i18nNamespaces || []),
      ],
    },
  }
}
```

My goal here is getting a dictionary with the title(an object) and the `title_en` values for all links in the array calling the function once.
Later, i pass this dictionary as a default property to the `_app` component:

```js
const FolioApp = ({ Component, pageProps, navProps }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyle = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side")

    if (jssStyle) {
      jssStyle.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyle)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <Meta />
      <DefaultSeo
        {...DefaultSEO}
        additionalMetaTags={[
          {
            name: "msapplication-TileColor",
            content: CMS_TILE_COLOR,
          },
          {
            name: "msapplication-config",
            content: "/favicon/browserconfig.xml",
          },
        ]}
      />
      {/* TODO: Add a proper theme */}
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Nav navLinks={navProps} />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <Footer navLinks={navProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  )
}
```

`navLinks` is the property and I pass it to the `footer` and `nav`. It works most of the time when the page does exist; but, it does not work when we get a `404` error page or even in the index:
[image]

I'm getting an empty `navLinks` in errors or in the index page. Why?

**UPDATE:**
Now, i tried to solve it using `Promise.all` in order to join all fetched data once before to pass it to props:

```
await Promise.all(
    menu_links.map(async ({ label }) => {
      const { title, title_en } = await getLocalizedTitle(label)
      navProps[label] = { title, title_en }
    })
  )
```

It did works but I didn't like this solution so much.

I searched through the [`cms-strapi`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-strapi) example and I found it gets the whole data from a single fetch, which is the best since `getInitialProps` is executed just one time and performs better than making separate fetching for each different type required data.

So, I change my fetching function thanks to the **strapi** [documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/graphql.html#query-api), I remade the function to get all data once before to pass it to properties.

It solves the problem rendering the menú but it does not solve the next problem which I get with both `Promise.all` and fetching solution:
[image]

As you can see, every time I go to the index page, I get that bug, and it happens because it is fetching using `localhost:3000/undefined/graphql` instead to `localhost:1337/graphql`, which is settled as `process.env.API_URL` by default, as `process.env.API_URL`; this does just happen when I'm redirecting from every page to **Home**(index), and sometimes when it gets 404 or 500 errors.

I don't understand it very well.

How can I handle this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool, finally, we could handle it in a next way.

First of all, taking a look at the **NextJS** examples for the main [post](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/cms-strapi/pages/posts/%5Bslug%5D.js) page we can realize it is using a function for fetching the post and another additional post; going deep on this [function](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/bcd1ba622e251b264c5b8e5149f7e6218a0df525/examples/cms-strapi/lib/api.js#L85), we can see it is just fetch for getting the whole data: it is not getting the data part by part using different fetch function, instead, it uses a **GraphQL** query to get all required data.

Following this way, we refactorize our function to get the whole names in a single object as fetching response:

```js
export async function getPageTitlesBySlugSet(slugSet) {
  const data = await fetchAPI(
    `query PageTitleBySlug($where: JSON){
      pages(where: $where) {
        slug
        title_en
        title {
          title_es
          title_tr
        }
      }
    }`,
    {
      variables: {
        where: { slug_in: slugSet },
      },
    }
  )

  return data?.pages
}
```

The idea is getting all pages with the slug existing in the `navLinks`, but how? We can think straight to use filter(as a **GraphQL** feature), but testing it in the **Strapi**'s GraphQL console, we can't see the filer options; what can we do? READ THE DOCUMENTATION, effectively, we can use `field_in` to [filter](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/graphql.html#query-api) any object which field matches in an array value; so, passing our slug from `navLinks` as a dictionary we can get all pages matching with wanted slugs:

```js
const navProps = await getPageTitlesBySlugSet(menu_links.map(({ label }) => label))
```

Cool, now we can get all data at once in an easier way. Cool, now we can pass `navProps` to the footer and nav components as property and we will handle it in order to localize them:

```
{navLinks &&
                Object.keys(navLinks).length !== 0 &&
                menu_links.map(({ key, href, label }) => (
                  <Link href={href} key={key} passHref>
                    <MenuItem>{localizedTitle(label)}</MenuItem>
                  </Link>
                ))}
```

Cool, but still we have a problem here: sometimes going to the index give us problems because it tries to fetch using the **API** URL, but it just can be accessed from the server, it is not public for the client; hence, it can't fetch correctly, giving us an error.

How to solve it? Same, in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) it says we must use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` as a prefix for each variable which we want to could be accessed from the client-side too. So, we put it and it solves our problem, now we can navigate to the index page from every page in the site.

That's all.

There is still a slow time problem which we will handle later.